# printing python Post request

Tags: python, http-post, urllib2

I am trying to print the POST request that I am doing using my python script. I was wondering if there is a way to print the post request so as to see how the parameters are passed through the script which I wish to compare it with the browser. I read through the urllib2 api but was not able to find a function that could help me in printing my POST request. Any pointers on this is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using [`urllib2.Request`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html?highlight=urllib2#urllib2.Request), you must provide the body of the POST request as an *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* string.

Since you are responsible for building the POST body, you can easily print or log it.

**Edit**

There is also [`urllib2.Request.get_data()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html?highlight=urllib2#urllib2.Request.get_data). Maybe you can us this.

**Edit 2**

Use it like this:

```
req = urllib2.Request("http://example.com/", "foo:bar")
print req.get_method()    # => 'POST'
print req.get_data()      # => 'foo:bar'

res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print res.getcode()       # => 200
print res.headers.items() # => [('transfer-encoding', 'chunked'), ...
```

Comment: Great thanks to you, this is what I was looking for!! I also managed to get the data using a tool called WebScarab.